# Function return type error with future.onComplete

Tags: scala, callback, future

I am using Scala

I have a method that returns an object , in this method i am using future with onComlpete callback

```
def xyzFunction (id : Int) : Abc = {

var abcObj = new Abc
 var RetunedLists = new MutableList[ArtistImpl]()
val future:Future[MutableList[Abc]] = ask(SomeActor,Message(id)).mapTo[MutableList[Abc]]
        future.onComplete {
         case Success(result) =>
           RetunedLists = result
           abcObj = RetunedLists.get(0)
          println("name : " + abcObj.name)


         case Failure(e) =>
        println("printStackTrace"+e.printStackTrace)


    }
 abcObj
}
```

the problem is when i run the code the it prints name on console bt the object that this functions is empty

help me please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the future hasn't completed by the time that `xyzFunction` completes. This means that `abcObj` hasn't been set (in the `future.onComplete` block), so it is still equal to its initial value (from the line `var abcObj = new Abc`).

To ensure `xyzFunction` returns a valid value for `abcObj`, you can wait on the future to complete (eg. via `Await.result(future, timeoutValue)`).

Better, though, would be to return a `Future[Abc]`, chaining results as futures (using `map`, `flatMap`, and similar methods) all the way up the line and resolving as late as possible. For example, if working with the Play framework, use `Action.async` and let Play handle resolving the future internally for you.

Comment: i think i can use Try to solve this problem , 
if i do like this, val future:Future[Try [MutableList[Abc]]] and then i can use map function with future like future map{
case Success => {//code
}
case failure => {//code
}
}
what do you think does it make sense?

Comment: and i am not using Play so i have to find another way

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi It will depend heavily on what happens in the "{//code}" blocks, and on what your return type is. My recommendation is to return `Future[Abc]` (or more generally `Future[X]` for some suitable X) from this and as many other functions as possible, leaving a small, top-level core that actually waits for the future(s) to complete (whether it is Play actions, the end-points of web service calls, an application's main method, an engine loop within that, or whatever is appropriate).

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi Try to think of your functions as building a script for what should happen (rather than actually doing the work within the functions), which script is only "executed" at the very "end" - generally just before any output would be provided (print statements, file writes, HTTP replies, or whatever).